# Streaming Music with Wi-Fi Direct

Tags: audio-streaming, wifi-direct

I'm trying to make an Android app that will let users stream music from one device and play it on others using Wi-Fi Direct, all playing simultaneously. I have found android.com tutorials for [Wi-Fi Direct](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html) connectivity and for [File-sharing](http://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html), but I simply want to stream it on the guest device(s), not entirely share the file.

Also, I want to allow the users to stream without necessitating an Internet connection, so Wi-Fi Direct seems like the best option currently. Are there any additional technologies that will help me do this?